# Calling a PL/SQL procedure and looping through the returned ref cursor in jython

Tags: plsql, jython

I have a PL/SQL procedure defined as such:

```
PROCEDURE get_rates(
                  in_last_sync_time  IN     TIMESTAMP                    
                 ,out_resultset      OUT    t_rates
                 );
```

I'm trying to call this procedure from jython and loop through the results that are returned as a ref cursor in the OUT parameter and I can't make it work.

Regards,

Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

For me works (of course I have other procedure name):

```
from java.sql import DriverManager, Types
...
proc = db.prepareCall("{ call revint(?,?) }")
proc.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER)
proc.setInt(1, arg1)
proc.execute()
n2 = proc.getInt(2)
```